# How can I clear the entire form for a fresh start? - to include inserted pictures

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I was tasked to create a user form with specific functions and was able get everything to work accept for the clear form button. I was able to clear everything from the form (textbox's, combobox's & checkboxes), but not sure how to clear a picture if one was inserted without delete the entire option. I want the user to start fresh when they select clear form. I have attached some pictures to help clarify what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks for your help.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()[enter image description here][1]
    question_clear = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to clear the form?      ", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Question")

    If question_clear = 7 Then Exit Sub 'nothing will happen because user clicked no

    If question_clear = 6 Then
        TextBox20.Value = ""
        TextBox21.Value = ""
        TextBox22.Value = ""
        TextBox23.Value = ""
        TextBox24.Value = ""
        TextBox25.Value = ""

        currentqty.Value = ""
        requiredqty.Value = ""

        ComboBox1.Value = ""
        ComboBox2.Value = ""

        CheckBox1.Value = False
        CheckBox2.Value = False
        CheckBox3.Value = False
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Try this `PictureBox1.Image = Nothing`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Rey. Please take a moment to read the guidelines in the Help Center about asking questions on the site. You should post CODE, not a screenshot of your code, so that people can copy/paste it for testing purposes.

Comment: My apologies. I have edited the question to where the code is in the correct place and easy to copy/paste. I'm still new at this. I tried using PictureBox1.Image = Nothing, but came up with a "run-time error '424': Object Required"

Answer (score 0):

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


question_clear = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to clear the form?      ", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Question")

If question_clear = 7 Then Exit Sub 'nothing will happen because user clicked no

If question_clear = 6 Then

TextBox20.Value = ""
TextBox21.Value = ""
TextBox22.Value = ""
TextBox23.Value = ""
TextBox24.Value = ""
TextBox25.Value = ""

currentqty.Value = ""
requiredqty.Value = ""
discqty.Value = ""

ComboBox1.Value = ""
ComboBox2.Value = ""

CheckBox1.Value = False
CheckBox2.Value = False
CheckBox3.Value = False


End If

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("picture").Select
'Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="picture"
Selection.InlineShapes(1).Delete
Selection.InsertAfter ""
'ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Range:=Selection.Range, _
'   Name:="picture"

End Sub
```